# nmap - protocol discovery doesn't work with fragmented packets

Tags: firewalls, nmap, tcp

Using nmap to do a protocol discovery `(nmap myhost -sO)` identifies the following on my target. Note reason switch is also used.

```
 PROTOCOL STATE SERVICE REASON
1        open  icmp    echo-reply ttl 255
6        open  tcp     proto-response ttl 255
```

If I then add the -f to fragment the packets to evade ids / firewall `(nmap myhost -sO -f)`

the scan no longer reports TCP as a protocol and only reports ICMP

```
PROTOCOL STATE SERVICE REASON
1        open  icmp    echo-reply ttl 255
```

Why does fragmenting the packets stop detection of TCP, is the firewall actively dropping these or does it not understand them?

Update:

I tried manually setting mtu in increments of 8 until I discovered TCP again and this occurs at mtu 24 . So `nmap myhost -sO -mtu 24`

and it's back to

```
PROTOCOL STATE SERVICE
1        open  icmp
6        open  tcp
```

Comment: can you sniff on the target side to see if they are being dropped? We can't tell you what the firewall or the host is doing without more data

Comment: No, i'm not able to do that. I was hoping to get an idea of what this type of response might indicate as this doesn't appear to be a regular case. I have added further info to the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have a firewall somewhere that is dropping packets for which it cannot make a determination of policy. A MTU of 24 is enough for the full IP header plus the source and destination ports of the TCP header. The next lowest valid MTU is 16, which is not enough to include the destination IP address. The firewall probably does not reassemble packets, so without enough to make a determination it drops the inbound packet. For ICMP, on the other hand, all that is needed may be the protocol number.